# "error: stray '\XXX' in C++ program": Why does this happen?

Tags: c++, vim, text

I'm writing a little program in C++, and come across a strange error:

```
src/Makefile/Tool.cpp:42:3: error: stray ‘\302’ in program
src/Makefile/Tool.cpp:42:3: error: stray ‘\240’ in program
```

I'm writing this program in Vim and the corresponding line (showing hidden characters) is:

```
>--->---std::vector<std::string> { "--debug" }$
```

**This question is not** about resolving this error, as I just have to copy back the line and the error-cause disappear.

It seems that the error is caused by some characters even hidden by Vim after activating all relative options!

**The question is** about what could have caused those errors.

Comment: Why don't you post the real code?

Comment: It is the real code. You want the whole scope? I didn't though it was useful, but if needed I can.

Comment: What? The real code is containing `>--->---`? and `$` at the end?

Comment: @Nawaz: Those are vim list characters (visible whitespace).

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Weird. With those characters,how can anyone say anything about the real problem?

Comment: @Nawaz: They're colourable. Visible white space is a good thing.

Comment: This particular stray character has been observed by copy pasting code through Skype Chat.

Comment: How did the [Option +  Space experiment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663565/error-stray-xxx-in-c-program-why-does-this-happen/18971009#comment9313293_7663664) turn out?

Comment: In a different context ([PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) scripts on Windows), the same character will result in: *"Â : The term 'Â' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. ... CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Â:String) [], CommandNotFoundException ... FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException"*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`"\302\240"` is UTF-8 for `U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE`. Vim won’t normally highlight it as anything special, so it’s possible for one to sneak in even if you have `'list'` mode enabled.

You can highlight them with:

```
:set listchars+=nbsp:.
```

or any character you like.

Comment: Thank you, but why is this character in my code? I just edit it with vim and nothing else, so I don't know where may it come from :/

Comment: @Geoffroy are you sure you didn't copy-paste any code from a webpage or a manpage or something?

Comment: @Josh Lee thanks for the settings, it was missing :) But any idea why is it in my code?

Comment: @Geoffroy, what is your keyboard layout? Mine is BÉPO and I can easily insert NBSPs with Shift-space.

Comment: Default Mac OS French, this character is not easily available

Comment: One additional comment: if you have doubts about a space character (or any character) in `vim`, position the cursor on it and enter `ga`.  This will display the encoding in the control line.

Comment: @Geoffroy Are you sure that Option+Space won't do it?

Comment: Good question, I never tested. When back home I check this out, thanks

Comment: In case someone almost misses @xoolive's comment like I did, you can replace these in Vim with `:%s/\%o302//g` and you might also need `:%s/\%o240//g`.

Comment: 302 and 240 are octal numbers (decimal 194 160. Hexadecimal 0xC2 0xA0).

Answer (score 10):

As aforementioned, it is due to some not visible characters in your source.

One great solution for this is to edit your file in octal mode and you will be able "to see" these characters:

```
od -c MyClass.hpp
```

Then you can see the "strangers" in the octal flow:

```
0001240   t       s   t   r   i   n   g   &       n   a   m   e       )
0001260       { **302 240**   t   h   i   s   -   >   n   a   m   e       =
0001300       n   a   m   e   ;       }  \n  \n  \n  \t  \t  \t  \t   /
```

These two characters in bold are the cause of messages like:

> error: stray ‘\302’ in program

You can then remove them, and rebuild.

Comment: +1 for your solution, well explained and even works for any other character ;)

Comment: The platform ought to be stated. Is it Linux?

Comment: A [similar comprehensive answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc/54352836#54352836) (for Windows).

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem came from copying my code over from a web browser.

I tried doing a `:%s/ / /g` in Vim to replace all spaces with real spaces, but this has failed.

I deleted the leading white space of all lines reporting this error and inserted the space characters again. This is labour intensive, but appears to be the only solution I could find.

Comment: If the stray is `\302`, you can use `:% s,\%o302,,g`

Comment: There isn't any need to it manually. It can probably be done by [regular expression search/replace for the Unicode code point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc/54352836#54352836) - `\x{00A0}`. I would surprised if Vim couldn't do it. It works fine in Notepad++ (Windows) and Geany (Linux).

Comment: Note: The notation is different in [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) (and probably others): `\u00A0` (instead of `\x{00A0}`)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was the character encoding for the spaces before each line. This happened due to copying from notes programs that was synced up with [Exchange Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Exchange_Server) and [iCloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICloud). All I needed to do is apply and replace all using [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) to all the strange spaces with normal ones and everything compiled normally again.