# output of AT command c++ code

Tags: c++, gsm, at-command

I wrote the following code which sends a simple message to my mobile with GSM SM5100B. But it does not work. I would like to check the outputs of each printf line with c++ code. 
For example

```
AT+CMFG=1
ok
AT+CMGS="69******"
ok
```

etc.
Is there any why to implement this?

My code

```
#include <stdio.h> // standard input / output functions
#include <string.h> // string function definitions
#include <unistd.h> // UNIX standard function definitions
#include <fcntl.h> // File control definitions
#include <errno.h> // Error number definitions
#include <termios.h> // POSIX terminal control definitionss
#include <time.h>   // time calls

int open_port(void)
{
int fd; // file description for the serial port
fd = open("/dev/ttyAMA0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if(fd == -1) // if open is unsucessful
{
    printf("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyAMA0. \n");
}
else
{
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
    printf("port is open.\n");
}

return(fd);
} //open_port

int configure_port(int fd)      // configure the port
{
struct termios port_settings;      // structure to store the port settings in

cfsetispeed(&port_settings, B9600);    // set baud rates
cfsetospeed(&port_settings, B9600);

port_settings.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;    // set no parity, stop bits, data bits
port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
port_settings.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
port_settings.c_cflag |= CS8;

tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &port_settings);    // apply the settings to the port
return(fd);

}  

void init_gsm()
{
 printf("AT+CMGF=1\r\n");
 sleep(3);
 printf("AT+CMGS=\"+34603****\"\r\n");
 sleep(3);
 //printf("Hello\r\n%c",26); 
 printf("Hello\x1A");
 sleep(3);
// printf("\x1A");

}
int main(void)
{
int fd = open_port();
configure_port(fd);
sleep(5);
//query_modem(fd);
    init_gsm();
return(0);

}
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific? Just saying "it does not work" doesn't really tell us much.

Comment: Although it might have something to do with you not writing anything to the modem?

Comment: I mean I do not have results...I have only port is open and the 3 printf lines. I think I need a code to read buffer

Comment: What you need is code to write to the modem ([`write`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/write.html)) and read from it ([`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html)). Experiment with those functions first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most seriously, you are not waiting for the final result code after sending an AT command. Using `sleep` is not a valid solution. You **MUST** fix this to do proper parsing of the response you get back from the modem. See the following answers for more details, [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16404193/23118), [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446523/23118).

Then your `init_gsm` function ought to have an `int fd` argument to use for sending the AT commands to as well as reading the response from.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ method is that you use a combination of `stringstream` and `write`.

```
stringstream ss;
string number;

cout << "Enter phone number to send to:");  
cout.flush();
cin >> number;
ss << "AT+CMGS=\"" << number << "\"\r\n";
string str = ss.str();
write(fd, str.c_str(), str.length());
```