# C Compiling: error: stray '\4' in program ; octal flow?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, cc

I am trying to compile a load of *.c* files.

(1) The files compile OK, using `cc`

```
cc -Wall -Wextra -Wunreachable-code -ggdb -O0 *.c
```

(2) Then, I need to make a static library from the final output, to use in a C++ program. So I do:

```
ar cru liborientdb-c.a *.o
```

(3) It works OK. However, when I come to compile the C++ program *testme.cpp* that includes the library in line #1,

```
(line 1 of testme.cpp)
#include "liborientdb-c.a"
```

Compile step:

```
cc testme.cpp
```

I get this error:

```
liborientdb-c.a:117:22: error: stray '\3' in program
liborientdb-c.a:117:263: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
liborientdb-c.a:117:22: error: stray '\17' in program
liborientdb-c.a:117:265: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
liborientdb-c.a:117:283: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
liborientdb-c.a:117:22: error: stray '\22' in program
liborientdb-c.a:117:287: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
liborientdb-c.a:117:22: error: stray '\1' in program
liborientdb-c.a:117:289: warning: null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]
liborientdb-c.a:117:22: error: stray '\362' in program
....
```

So, following the advice on some others posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663565/error-stray-xxx-in-program-why), I believe the errors could be due to messed up encoding.

So I used 'od -c' and to try and trace where the "octal flow" is getting messed up. The output for one of my .o files after with 'od -c' looks pretty bad, so I think that could be the reason.

For example,

```
0000000 177   E   L   F 002 001 001  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000020 001  \0   >  \0 001  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000040  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0   `   (  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000060  \0  \0  \0  \0   @  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0   @  \0 026  \0 023  \0
0000100   U   H 211   ?   H 203   ? 020   H 211   }   ?   H 211   u   ?
0000120   H 213   E   ?   H 213  \0   H 213   @  \b   H 205   ?   t 023
0000140   H 213   E   ?   H 213  \0   H 213   @  \b   H 211   ?   ?  \0
```

How can I fix this though? I actually followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets) and ran this on my library source files:

```
recode UTF8..ISO-8859-15 *.c
```

The response is the files remain unchanged (the last modified date is still old). So then I open my .c files and see they are in UTF-8, which is apparently a subset of ASCII. So it would not seem to be a issue then.

But the .o files still look weird.

How can I proceed?

Comment: You are including a .a file?

Comment: UTF-8 is not a subset of ASCII.

Comment: It isn't listed here as a stray error in the question, but \177 (before "[ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format)") is a signature for [the compiler chewing on a binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547750/cannot-use-sourcecpp-from-a-file#comment134364000_48547750) (executable) file, usually due to [some problem with the build system/make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73410284/). The very first byte of an ELF file is 0x7F (octal 177, decimal 127), followed by the three (in ASCII) characters E, L, and F.

Comment: A canonical is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1)* (though should probably only be used for UTF-8 sequences).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at:

```
#include "liborientdb-c.a"
```

.a files are not C source files. Or even text files for that matter.

Usually, the .a files are added on the final link line of the compilation.

```
cc -o something file.o file2.o liborientdb-c.a etc etc
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry - it's late in the day :D

Answer (score 4):

You are including a binary file in your *.cpp* source:

```
(line 1 of testme.cpp)
#include "liborientdb-c.a"
```

Look for a header file named "liborientdb-c.h", and include that (guessing, you probably want to include all of the appropriate **.h* header files).

And your makefile should link against the above *.a* file.