# Simple Error Compiling C code

Tags: c, include

Here's the error I get:

```
genlib.h:225:1: error: stray ‘\32’ in program
```

`genlib.h` is defined in: http://pastebin.com/KgM3J24W

Here's my code:

```
/*
 * file: hello.c
 * -----------
 *  This program prints the message "Hello World."
 *  On the screen. The program is taken from the 
 *  classic C reference text "The C Programing
 *  Language" by Brian Kemighan and Dennis Richie.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "genlib.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have an invisible character (`032` octal) on line 225. Check your file (with a hex editor, another text editor, etc.) Also, I do not understand why you need some random header (`"genlib.h"`) for compiling a trivial Hello World.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663565/error-stray-xxx-in-program-why

Comment: @user3477950 answering your question of why I need to use (`"genlib.h"`). The reason I need to use is because my professor is teaching us C with this library.

Comment: @TittySlap but you still don't need it for a hello world. Maybe the problem is in his header file. Try removing it and re-compiling. (Also, in the meantime, did you check that line using a hex editor?)

Comment: @user3477950 I have very minimal programing experience, and i don't understand how to use hex editors. I don't think I am supposed to use that in the first place, since I am only taking introduction to C programing.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file **genlib.h**, go to the very last line where there is a garbage character (as can be seen in your linked page http://pastebin.com/KgM3J24W), remove that character, and then save the file again.

If your editor doesn't show the garbage character, perhaps you can try to create a new, empty file called **genlib2.h**, copy the content from **genlib.h** (without the garbage), save **genlib2.h**, and then rename **genlib2.h** to **genlib.h**.

The invisible character (032 octal) can also be written as **^Z**, and was used in MS-DOS and old Windows to mean end-of-file. Someone probably added it by mistake when entering the content of **genlib.h**.